# Beginner - print total words from inputted text, also print length

Tags: python

I've been programming in Python for just a couple weeks, I've been given a program to print total words from inputted text, also print the length of all letters in the first print total. I've only learned, for, if, range, strings, lists, and normal input/raw_inputs. I've tried coding a few different ways that have been completely unsuccessful. Any ideas I can bounce off of? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please refer to stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

For the length of the string and how many words are contained

```
import re
string = raw_input("Enter string: ")
print(len(string)) #String length
print(len(re.findall(r'\w+', string)) #Count of words
```

Do note that you have to use `input()` rather than `raw_input()` if you're using Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Make a rule about words. For example, "words are any letters except space, tab, newline".

Now iterate over the input using `for`. Check each letter to see whether it is a "word character" or a "non-word character".

Keep a "in-word/out-of-word" state that tracks what the last letter was. Every time you move from in-word to out-of-word, based on the current letter, you have reached the end of a new word and can add one to your count.

```
input_text = "Here is   some  \t\ntext.that.you.might like!"
in_word = False
word_count = 0

for ch in input_text:
    if ch == ' ' or ch == '\t' or ch == '\n':
        # Not a word character
        if in_word:
            in_word = False
            word_count += 1
    else:
        in_word = True

# At end of string, check for one last word
if in_word:
    word_count += 1

print("# words:", word_count)
```

Comment: For the  "if" statements, i'm getting an error telling me, "word_count" isn't defined. I'm not positive on how I should define this.

Comment: fixed - word_count = 0